# Get from email address with email parser

Tags: php

I am using this absolute amazing piece of code: https://github.com/plancake/official-library-php-email-parser/blob/master/PlancakeEmailParser.php

But the one thing it is missing is the ability to get the From email address.

I have simple added:

```
public function getFromEmail()
{
    if (!isset($this->rawFields['from']))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->rawFields['from'];
}
```

But how would I get only the email address part at the moment it returns: `John Smith<john@gmail.com>`?

Also I would need this to work if the From address was only `john@gmail.com`?

Thanks to the answers this was the finished code:

```
public function getFromEmail()
{
    $email = trim($this->rawFields['from']);

    if(substr($email, -1) == '>'){
        $fromarr = explode("<",$email);
        $mailarr1 = explode(">",$fromarr[1]);
        $email = $mailarr1[0];
    }

    return $email;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into regular expressions as an option?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll if its the most reliable we to get the email no problem, this script is ran by cron at 2am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mailid='John Smith<john@gmail.com>';
$mailarr=explode("<",$mailid);
$mailarr1=explode(">",$mailarr[1]);
$just_emailid=$mailarr1[0];
```

Comment: How would I make this work if there is no name, ie there is no <

Comment: well i assumed by your question that you will be getting '<' each time. You might make a check using  strpos for '<' and if it is not there then don't run this code. Even using regex with uncertainity of '<' will cause problems

Answer (score 2):

This is a very simple regular expression:

```
$output = array();
preg_match("/.*<(.*?)>.*?/", $this->rawFields['from'], $output);
$email_address = $output[1];
```

Care though: If someone's name contains < or > it might cause a security vulnerability. The lazy operator (*.?) is used to ensure the last set of < > is used.

HTH

PS: Use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test Regular Expressions!